# How to print "<" and ">" stored in the variable using php?

Tags: php, html

```
<form id="preview-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <textarea class="codemirror-textarea" name="preview-form-comment" id="preview-form-comment"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
  <br>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js"></script>
  <input type="submit" onclick="savedata();" name="preview-form-submit" id="preview-form-submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I do `echo $_POST['preview-form-comment'];` in the  PHP script and the text in the textarea is `#include<stdio.h>` it only prints `#include` and takes the other part as a tag.

Comment: Just as a point of style (not related to the issue), it's highly unusual to see `<script` tags dumped inline into a form in the middle of a page like that. Normally people declare all the script and CSS links in the `<head>` section of the page if they can, so that they're loaded before any JavaScript code runs. Any specific reason you put them here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape any HTML characters that might be in your variable using [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
<?= htmlentities($comment) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars()` would do it.

Try it with `echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['preview-form-comment'])`